# divide two layerstacked images into one with header

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to divide two layerstacked images (.bsq) into one with a header. Each images contains 5 layers. Layer 1 of the first image should be divided with layer 1 of the second image and so on. The resulting image (.bsq) should also contain 5 layers and a header. I try for a long time, but it doesn't work, because I'm not sure how to do it. Maybe you can help me because I am an absolut beginner in programming python.

My Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import spectral


path_fileroot = 'D:/Documents/STUDIUM/GIT_Studium/Masterarbeit/originalBilder/'
path_outFile_root = 'D:/Documents/STUDIUM/GIT_Studium/Masterarbeit/originalBilder/original_bilder_12062014/'
path_images_root   = 'D:/Documents/STUDIUM/GIT_Studium/Masterarbeit/originalBilder/original_bilder_12062014/Einzelbilder/'
general_hdr = open (path_fileroot + 'Generalheader.hdr','r').read()

imagesHeader79 = spectral.open_image(path_images_root + 'TTC0079/TTC0079.hdr')
imagesHeader89 = spectral.open_image(path_images_root + 'TTC0089/TTC0089.hdr')

print imagesHeader79
print imagesHeader89

img79 = imagesHeader79.read_bands((0,1,2,3,4)) 
img89 = imagesHeader89.read_bands((0,1,2,3,4))

print img89
print img79

devideImg  = img89/(img79 * 1.0)    

out_img = open (path_outFile_root + 'TTC0079/TTC0079.bsq')
for i in range(np.shape(devideImg)[5]):
    out_img.write(devideImg[:,:,i])
out_img.close()
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: I am not sure how to save the resulting image in the right image array and to create an suitable header.